# How to add multiple packages to pubspec.yaml from command line?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can add a package to my `pubspec.yaml` file from command line using:

```
dart pub add foo
```

But how to add multiple packages?

```
dart pub add foo, bar // Doesn't work
```

Comment: Run the command multiple times. The command does not support adding multiple packages at the same time for now: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-add

Comment: But in the near future you can do it: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/3273 (I am guessing Dart 2.17 since 2.16 is closed for new features)

Comment: @julemand101 Thanks for sharing the link :) For now, yes, I've to run the command multiple times.

Comment: Ok, I have added an answer you can accept. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now (Dart 2.15.1), the Dart pub tool does not support adding multiple package dependencies in one command. You therefore need to run `pub add` for each package you want to add as dependency for your project.

A pull request for pub have recently being merged which adds support for adding multiple dependencies in one operation.

You can find the issue here: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/3273

And pull request here: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/pull/3283

Since this has happen rather recent, my own personal guess is, that this change is not going to be part of Dart 2.16 but rather Dart 2.17, since 2.16 has been closed for further development for some time to make it ready for release in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
for pkg in redux flutter_redux redux_sagas do; flutter pub add $pkg; done;
```

Obv add more packages as desired, space separated.